# Winscp library supports proxy over SFTP?

Tags: c#, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

Winscp library supports for HTTP proxy. Does it support over FTP and SFTP and how to define it?

Comment: **The WinSCP .NET assembly is a .NET wrapper around WinSCP’s scripting interface that allows your code to connect to a remote machine and manipulate remote files over SFTP, SCP, WebDAV and FTP sessions.** That's the first line that appears on the nuget page of winscp.

Comment: *"Proxy **over** SFTP"* - I assume you mean *"proxy **for** SFTP"* - *"Proxy over SFTP"* is something very different.